# How to save and reload Tensorflow/Keras and Keras-cv YOLO model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, yolov8

I have been working through the example of the Keras website:
https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8/
to build a YOLOv8 model in Tensorflow/Keras.  I have successfully trained a model, although I get an error when using the callback, so have removed the callback and tried to save the model manually once the model training has completed.

```
yolo.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=3
)
yolo.save('my_yolo_mdl.keras')

yolo_load=tf.keras.models.load_model('my_yolo_mdl.keras')
```

I get a warning here that the model is not compiled, so I compile it in the same way as i did before training:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(
    learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
    global_clipnorm=GLOBAL_CLIPNORM,
)

yolo_load.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, classification_loss="binary_crossentropy", box_loss="ciou"
)
```

Then when I try to predict using the compiled model and an image of shape (1,:,:,3) I get an error:

```
yolo_load.predict(img)

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2440, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2425, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2413, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_cv/models/object_detection/yolo_v8/yolo_v8_detector.py", line 616, in predict_step
        return self.decode_predictions(outputs, args[-1])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_cv/models/object_detection/yolo_v8/yolo_v8_detector.py", line 609, in decode_predictions
        return self.prediction_decoder(box_preds, scores)

    TypeError: '_DictWrapper' object is not callable
```

This input array works as expected if I use the original model, rather than the one that was loaded in.  Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: doesn't work.

In the load_model function, set the `compile` argument to false

```
yolo_load=tf.keras.models.load_model('my_yolo_mdl.keras', compile=False)
```

Then compile it again the same way as shown in your second code block.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue.  I still get a model with the incorrect size outputs.  The only work around I have found is to create a new yolov8 backbone with the correct output architecture and then load in the weights from the saved .keras model.  This works, but you have to know the architecture of the original model which is a little annoying!

Comment: I ran it again and yeah it didn't work. Now I'm really confused why it seemed to once before.

Comment: If you use save_weights on your trained model, remake the same model with compile again like the second block and call `yolo_load.load_weights` you don't need to mess with the backbone architecture.